# Why does `expr_text(enquo())` return a tilde in `cli` vs. `deparse(substitute())`?

Tags: r, rlang

What is it about quosure's that cause the tilde ~ below?

```r
library(rlang)
library(cli)
my_cli <- function(arg) {
  cli::cli_abort(c(
    "*" = "{.arg {deparse(substitute(arg))}}",
    "*" = "{.arg {expr_text(enquo(arg))}}",
    "*" = "{.arg {expr_text(enexpr(arg))}}"
  ))
}
my_cli(my_arg)
#> Error in `my_cli()`:
#> • `my_arg`
#> • `~my_arg`
#> • `my_arg`
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. └─global my_cli(my_arg)
#>  2.   └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  3.     └─rlang::abort(...)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think this is an effect of `expr_text()` which unwraps the quosure. See examples section here https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quo_label.html